# Spring MVC localization - properties file not being found

Tags: java, spring-mvc, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to get basic localization working in a new Spring MVC app. I've tried everything I can think of but always end up with the following exception, regardless of what I do. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

I've tried adding the properties file to every single directory but it still gives me an error. Once I get it working I'll systematically remove extras.

The exception:

```
07/13/2012 21:06:00.178 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource] No properties file found for [messages] - neither plain properties nor XML
07/13/2012 21:06:00.178 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource] No properties file found for [messages_en] - neither plain properties nor XML
07/13/2012 21:06:00.179 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource] No properties file found for [messages_en_US] - neither plain properties nor XML
07/13/2012 21:06:00.182 [ERROR] [org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag] No message found under code 'test.testMessage' for locale 'en_US'.
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'test.testMessage' for locale 'en_US'.
```

Here's the JSP entry (the fmt:message just shows ???test.testMessage??? while the spring:message blows up):

```
<h2><fmt:message key="test.testMessage" />!</h2>
<h2><spring:message code="test.testMessage" />!</h2>
```

Here's the configuration in my comparison-servlet.xml file:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

Here's the war structure (note that I added the messages.properties at pretty much every level):

```
messages.properties
src
    messages.properties
    main
        messages.properties
        java
        ...
        resources
            messages.properties
        webapp
            index.jsp
            messages.properties
            WEB-INF
                comparison-servlet.xml
                web.xml
                messages.properties
                jsp
                messages.properties
                    compare.jsp
                    globalIncludes.jsp
            classes
                messages.properties
            resources
                messages.properties
    test
        ...
```

Any idea why it can't find a file that is definitely there? Do I need to explicitly set something regarding the classpath?

Comment: By the way, I'm currently running this on Weblogic. I've considered installing Tomcat to see if it works but want to exhaust my options before resorting to a new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with the war file itself. While the properties files were being copied to the target directory and showed up as if they were included in the build, the maven pom file was set to explicitly exclude properties files from the built artifact.

Once I removed this from my pom file, everything started working fine:

```
<configuration>
    <packagingExcludes>**/*.properties</packagingExcludes>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to put messages.properties under WEB-INF directory inside any folder and set the path with `basename` property.

For example:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/i18n/messages" />
</bean>
```

See Javadoc [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setBasename%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I tried that again and it still errors, however I noticed something different in the logs when I did it this time. Before there were 3 error lines where it looked for messages, messages_en, and messages_en_US but now there is only a search for messages_en_US ([/WEB-INF/classes/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name /WEB-INF/classes/messages, locale en_US). Is there something else I need to add to ensure it looks for the default messages and messages_us first?

Comment: Looking at this again, the error messages are now different too. Originally it was "No properties file found for [messages] - neither plain properties nor XML" but now it is "[/WEB-INF/classes/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name /WEB-INF/classes/messages, locale en_US". Not sure what the difference between these two is though.

Comment: In playing with this more, the error listed in my first post is what I get when using the ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, regardless of whether I supply a path to the file or not. The error listed in my previous comment is what I get with the ResourceBundleMessageSource, regardless of whether I supply a path, use classname:, or use just the name of the file without an extension.

Comment: Notice that in my example I put .properties file inside `i18n` folder, every file with its locale extension: `messages.properties` (default), `messages_en_US.properties`, `messages_fr_FR.properties`, etc. Have you tried to put files in a folder inside WEB-INF, and not inside WEB-INF/classes? Maybe this is not important, but you can give it a try.

Comment: You can find the difference between `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and `ResourceBundleMessageSource` [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html). They are almost the same, but `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`, has a reloadable cache.

Comment: I read just about everything I could find and tried every variation - turns out the maven pom file just had a configuration in it to exclude properties files, which means no matter where I told it to look, it was never going to find it. I updated the build file, put the file in /src/main/resources (which gets copied to /WEB-INF/classes during the build), and set the ReloadableRBMS to point at /WEB-INF/classes and it works great now. Thanks for all the feedback.